# Reading a cookie(which is an object) in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to read a cookie in plain javascript only. I'm not using any jquery cookie library.

Here's how my cookie looks:

```
var task_cookie = {
                   task1 : getTask('task1') 
                 , task2 : getTask('task2')
                 , task3: getTask('task3')
                 , task4: getTask('task4') 
                 , task5: getTask('task5')                  
 };

document.cookie = "task_cookie=" + JSON.stringify(task_cookie)+";path=/;domain=.task.com";
```

Now, I'm trying to read the value of task_cookie later on a different page

I found this code on stackoverflow

```
function read_cookie(name) {
 var result = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
 result && (result = JSON.parse(result[1]));
 return result;
}
```

But this would give me the whole task_cookie.I however want to grab each key value inside the task_cookie. I want something like this:

```
$.cookie('task1')
$.cookie('task2')
```

However this is very easy in jquery after I stringify. But forsome reason I need to use pure javascript. How can I get individual values of task1 , task2 etc which are inside the task_cookie object? I'm having a hard time figuring this out :/

Comment: Since you're stringifying it, I'm pretty sure you have to get thefull object back, but then you can get the individual parts out of that. Also, if you're going for more than one section, I would think it would be faster since there's only one parse necessary.

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "if you're going for more than one section" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is returning the entire object, so you can just select an individual cookie from the function:

```
read_cookie('task_cookie')['task1'];
```

Or something similar. The above will just return the `task1`, but you can iterate through all the tasks.

Better yet, you can make the `read_cookie` function an object method and just return the cookie object to a property of the parent object.

```
var cookieHandler = {
    get: function(name) {
        //code to get cookies 
        //push to cookies array 
    },
    cookies: []
};
```

That way you don't have to create a bunch of instances for a global function every time you iterate over a task.

Answer (score 0):

So read the value from the cookie after you get the object.

```
function read_cookie(name) {
 var result = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('tasj_cookie=([^;]+)'));
 result && (result = JSON.parse(result[1]));
 return result ? result[name] : null;
}
```

Better yet, use localstorage and not cookies.

```
localstorage.setItem("task1", getTask('task1'));


function read_storage (name) {
    return localstorage.getItem(name);  //might need to use JSON.parse() depending on the data
}
console.log(read_storage("task1"));
```